# Is it really possible to use Twilio on Java App Engine using REST?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, twilio

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346657/how-to-use-twilio-with-gwt-in-google-appengine-java), it's possible to use Twilio on Java App Engine using rest.

But since Twilio isn't whitelisted there, does that mean you have to write your own library to work with Twilio calls?

Are there any examples of how to do this on App Engine?

Comment: Doesn't the linked question answer your question exactly?

Answer (score 4):

As the answer to that question indicates, the official client library *does not* work on GAE since it requires a class that GAE doesn't allow, so *yes*, you will have to write your own "library" to deal with twilio calls.

Thankfully, there are a large number of REST libraries out there that can do much of the heavy lifting for you.

As to examples, I don't know of any, but perhaps a google search would illuminate some.

Comment: Fun fact: we have an app on App Engine that uses the Twilio API to call our building's IVR system to turn the lights on after hours when we work late so we can click a button on a webpage instead of picking up our phones. I know, I know ... it's a horribly roundabout way to do something, but sometimes in life it's just easier to duct tape things together.